# Does the "eleventh metal" exist in the post-Final Empire world?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

I saw a table of all the metals and Atium was a God metal, not a normal metal with an opposite as it was in the first *Mistborn* novel. Also in that table they did not have Malatium, the eleventh metal. I would assume that Malatium still exists but now I'm not so sure. My final question is: does Malatium still exist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Malatium "exists" in the sense that it is still a legitimate chemical compound in the world. However, it is not really accurate to call it "the eleventh metal". It is an alloy of Atium + Gold, and not properly part of the 16 true allomantic metals.

### Allomantic Misconceptions

The diagram (which @daft_code already linked to, so I won't repeat it) from Brandon's site shows the chart of all 16 allomantic metals, plus the two "god" metals. From here, we can see a couple of things that the people in the initial series got wrong:

- There are 16 allomantic metals: 8 pure and 8 alloys; If you chart out what was "known" about allomancy in the original series, a mathematically-minded person could probably deduce from the extreme symmetry that there was more than one missing.
- Atium is not actually part of the set of allomantic metals; we learn at the end of the trilogy that it is the body of Ruin (like Lerasium, which is the body of Preservation)
- There are, in fact, Mistings for all of the metals, plus Atium and its alloys (originally, it was assumed that only a Mistborn could burn Atium or Gold, and none of the other "higher" metals were even known.)

All of those misconceptions have presumably been corrected by the time of Alloy of Law.

### Atium and Lerasium Alloys

As far as Malatium itself, it doesn't appear on the chart because it's an alloy of Atium, specifically Atium and Gold. Both Atium and Lerasium can form alloys with the other 16 metals. In the case of Lerasium, these alloys are what causes Mistings to be born in the first place (e.g. someone ingesting a Lerasium/Iron alloy would become an Iron Misting.)

In the case of Atium, we *only* know what Malatium does: it produces the Gold effect but on someone else. Note that this actually makes Atium/Malatium a *much better fit* for the positions held by Cadmium and Cerrobend, as "external" versions of Gold and Electrum, but [Word of God(*)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod) has declared that to be false.

We don't know what the other 15 alloys of Atium do, though they all have some enhanced "temporal or mental" effect. However, atium is *very* rare at this point: presumably, Sazed could produce more if he wanted, and Marsh still has a tiny stash (keeping him alive), but that's it.[[1](https://sites.google.com/site/brandonothology/QA-by-book/mistborn)] As far as the rest of the world goes, it doesn't exist anymore. That makes it unlikely that we'll see any of these other alloys any time soon.

(*) [Obligatory TV Tropes Warning Here]

Comment: "these alloys are what causes Mistings to be born in the first place" - not really being born and eating Lerasium are quite different things.

Answer (score 3):

There are 16 metals not counting the God metals.  The characters in the original mistborn never really understood allomancy fully.  So the concept of an 11th metal is based on a false premise (that there are only 10 metals).

As for malatium, I believe that each of the standard allomantic metals can be alloyed with atium.  The chart says that combining larasium with any allomantic metal and burning it turns that person into a misting of that metal.  I assume atium can be combined in a similar way, and that malatium is just one example.

[image]

Comment: Where is the eleventh metal, or Malatium in this chart?

Answer (score 3):

To add to deft_code's answer, the 11th metal is Malatium, which is an alloy of Atium and Gold.

As far as the existence of it, I would say technically yes.  Brandon has hinted that there is still Atium in the world, so an alloy of it would still be possible.

See [here](http://mistborn.wikia.com/wiki/Allomancy)

Comment: Actually, in the Hero of Ages they use up all of the atium. Also, If you look at the metal chart below it doesn't include malatium.

Comment: there is still atium in the world, it just all very well hidden.

Comment: Its not on the chart because Malatium is a unique metal.

Actually, I have a theory about the chart, and what we are lacking from it.

So, we look at it using our knowledge of the Cosmere.  The Cosmere has 3 realms, the Physical, the Mental, and the Spiritual.

Comment: Looking at the chart below, we definitely have Physical (Physical/Enhancement) and Mental (Mental/Temporal), so I would surmise that we have an additional "ring" on the chart  that has the Spiritual metals.  God metal alloys... spiritual, it just seems obvious, doesn't it?

o, we would have another 16 metals on the chart. 8 alloys of Larasium (which would create a misting), and 8 alloys of Atium, which would include Malatium.

Comment: I haven't seen any hints from Sanderson that there's *that much* missing from the understanding of allomancy as of *Alloy*. I know that Ruin and Preservation were both physically-aspected shards, which is why their influence created magic systems based on metal. More likely, each of the 16 shards would be a "god metal" under this system, but that would require other shards to somehow show up on Scadriel...

Comment: I don't think the other shards would have any god metal on Scadriel... otherwise we would have each and every Shardholder's presence on every shard in some form.  I just think alloys created from the 2 god metal would encompass the spiritual aspect, though because Ruin and Preservation were physically-aspected, these are very, very uncommon.

Who knows, hopefully we'll learn more in the next trilogy or Alloy of Law sequel.